# Can not show the rightbar button - ios sdk

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem

I had add image at my navigation bar and need to add the right bar refresh button.
But the right bar button can not show at the navigation after add.
Why?

Here the code add image at navigation bar:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"topbar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Here the add right bar button at `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh: )];

NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[refreshItem];
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```

Comment: Yes, I use this also can not show

Answer (score 2):

You should not add to self.navigationcontroller.

Do something like this will resolve your problem.

```
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = refreshItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh: )];      
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Refresh"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(rightButtoneClicked:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
```

Right this code in viewDidLoad and you get the refresh button on right side.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```

With:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
```